# Change word document Page orientation using OpenXML C# from a stream

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

I want to change a page orientation of word document using openXML. I am replacing a new paragraph and adding a table. After that i need to chnage the orientation of that page to Landscape

This is the code I am using

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true, openSettings))
                {
                    HtmlConverter converter = new HtmlConverter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart);
                    var newParagraphs = converter.Parse(GetTable1HTML());

                    var body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

                    //styling
                    var para1 = new Wordprocessing.Paragraph(new Wordprocessing.Run(newParagraphs)) { RsidParagraphAddition = "00BA2F0F", RsidParagraphProperties = "00BA2F0F", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00BA2F0F" };
                    Wordprocessing.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new Wordprocessing.ParagraphProperties();
                    Wordprocessing.SectionProperties sectionProp1 = new Wordprocessing.SectionProperties(new Wordprocessing.PageSize()
                    { Width = (UInt32Value)35840U, Height = (UInt32Value)22240U, Orient = Wordprocessing.PageOrientationValues.Landscape })
                    { RsidR = "00BA2F0F" };
                    paragraphProperties1.Append(sectionProp1);

                    //Table1
                    var paragraphsTable1 = body.Descendants<Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().
                        Where(e1 => e1.InnerText.Contains("<text to search>")).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (paragraphsTable1 == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    //para1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
                    paragraphsTable1.InsertBeforeSelf<Wordprocessing.Paragraph>(para1).Append(paragraphProperties1);
                    paragraphsTable1.Remove();}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `SectionProperties` to `Body` (or get if there any), not `ParagraphProperties`. Also don't know why do you set `Rsid` properties here.
Your code could will looks like

```
// styling
Wordprocessing.SectionProperties sectionProp1 = 
               body.Descendants<SectionProperties>()?.FirstOrDefault() ?? 
               body.AppendChild(new SectionProperties());

var pageSize = sectionProp1.Descendants<PageSize>()?.FirstOrDefault() ?? 
               sectionProp1.AppendChild(new Wordprocessing.PageSize());
pageSize.Width = 35840;
pageSize.Height = 22240;
pageSize.Orient = Wordprocessing.PageOrientationValues.Landscape;
```

If you will want to change properties again, you have to use something like

```
body.AppendChild(
     new Paragraph(
             new Run(
             new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
body.AppendChild(new SectionProperties());
```

Also youd try add `SectionType` in your example into `SectionProperties`, not sure, but may be that will works aswell.

```
Wordprocessing.SectionProperties sectionProp1 = new Wordprocessing.SectionProperties(
    new SectionType() { Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage },
    new Wordprocessing.PageSize()
                    { Width = (UInt32Value)35840U, Height = (UInt32Value)22240U, Orient = Wordprocessing.PageOrientationValues.Landscape })
                    { RsidR = "00BA2F0F" };
```